# Update QGIS didn't solve error "NUMPY driver was compiled against GDAL 2.1"

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, ubuntu, numpy

When I tried "zonal statistics" with QGIS, I encountered the following error.
**ERROR 1: NUMPY driver was compiled against GDAL 2.1 but current library version is 1.11**

I could find people who had same problem,

- [QGIS 2.18: Error in NUMPY and GDAL 2.1 [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234465/qgis-2-18-error-in-numpy-and-gdal-2-1)
- [QGIS 2.18.5 update breaks on Ubuntu 16.04 [closed]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233904/qgis-2-18-5-update-breaks-on-ubuntu-16-04)

so, I updated QGIS 2.18.5 to the latest version.
But I still have the problem.

Here's what I did.

1. Uninstalled QGIS 2.18.5 by "sudo apt-get remove qgis"
2. re-installed the latest version, that is, 2.18.7 as the follows.

   1. sudo apt-get update
   2. sudo apt-get -f install
   3. sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-provider-grass

Re-installed QGIS says its version is "2.18.7".
I think the above problem should have been solved already,
but I got exactly the same error.

Any ideas ?

--- Update ---

It seems that "sudo apt-get qgis" loads gdal-1.11 even though gdal-2.1 is installed. How can I make it load gdal-2.1 ?

Comment: Which repository did you install qgis from?